# Primefaces' gmaps autoresize

Tags: css, google-maps, jakarta-ee, primefaces, autoresize

I'm facing a slight problem using a **gmap** component: when I try to make component resizable (i.e. to set map's height and width both to 100% with help of CSS) the component shrinks and map itself become invisible. But if fixed height/width are set the component works fine. Is there a way to make automatic resize for gmap?

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought. You are applying the sizing to the actual #map or #map_content (or whatever) the holding div is on your page and not the map itself?

If you are only sizing the map and not the containing div, then 100% of 0 is still 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the CSS style. If anybody is still interested in solving this problem the code below works for me:

CSS:

```
html, body, form {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.mapClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

}

XHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <link href="./resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form> 
        <p:gmap widgetVar="gmtls" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" styleClass="mapClass"/>
    </h:form>  
</h:body>
</html>
```